# Using Managed Identity with Cosmos Db Table Api

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-managed-identity, azure-cosmosdb-tables

I am trying to connect to cosmos db table api using Managed Identity. According to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities), cosmos db supports Managed Identity. I couldn't find any documentation that says anything specific about table api. I am using [.Net standark SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table/dotnet-standard-sdk) but it doesn't seem to have support for Managed Identity.

Is it possible to use Managed Identity with Cosmos Db table api?

If yes, What should I do to use Managed Identity for CosmosDb table api?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Managed Identity with CosmosDB dataplane works only for [SQL API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/managed-identity-based-authentication).

Is it possible to use Managed Identity with Cosmos Db table api?

[image]

**No**

Comment: It seems to be possible to use MI with Table API. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-managed-identity

What I found is that probably the SDK does not support that behavior yet for Table API in Cosmos DB. Only for Storage account.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/32058#issuecomment-1293601799

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1. Ensure you're on the latest version of the `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` package
2. Ensure that you're using Azure.Identity (MSAL) as opposed to Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication (ADAL, which is deprecated)
3. Ensure that you've enabled managed identity for your app
4. Ensure that you've created a role assignment for that managed identity's object/application ID in your Cosmos database (either read only or read/write)
5. Get a `CosmosClient` with something similar to
   `var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient('yourCosmosClientDBUrl', new DefaultAzureCredential());`

`DefaultAzureCredential` is the Azure.Identity way of getting your access token to a service - it tries to look for authentication info in the following order:

1. Environment variables
2. Managed identity injected into the environment
3. Shared token cache credential
4. Visual Studio credential
5. Visual Studio Code credential
6. AZ CLI credential
7. Powershell Az credential
8. Interactive credential (popup browser window)

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is working for SQL api but not for Table API.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be possible to use MI with Table API.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-managed-identity

What I found is that probably the SDK does not support that behavior yet for Table API in Cosmos DB. Only for Storage account.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/32058#issuecomment-1293601799

I think that for now you should use connection strings or move to collections.

Comment: Isn't this adding identity to cosmosdb? The question is to connect to cosmosdb table api.